# Genymotion emulator shows white screen. not working

Tags: android, xml

Genymotion emulator shows white screen. it starts fine. but didn't get original screen. it shows only white screen.[image: this is picture]

Comment: try to use already given phone configuration in place of making custom such as nexus 4.

Comment: I tried. but nexus 4 also shows same white screen.

Comment: @vinodhkumar : Try Debugging your Launcher Activity, lets see where the app gets stuck.
Also please try to install the apk on the device.

Comment: no sir. when screen appear when I launch the emulator.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, genymotion just stayed glued to the taskbar and consistently showed the white screen no matter what I did. However, after so many hours of trying;

Press the combination <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd> click the taskbar icon for genymotion and select maximize.

It solved my problem.

I guess everything else was a bit overkill‍♂️

Comment: I used an external monitor and after disconnecting the monitor I was having this issue, Your answer solved it. Thanks

Comment: Solved my problem. I have even uninstalled and installed several times. ‍♂️

Answer (score 2):

Please Check Requirement of Genymotion and your system configuration. 
Also check for :

1. OpenGL Version, if its less than 2.0 then update it to 2.0 or higher.
2. Graphics card driver: Make sure its the latest version

Comment: Thank you sir. How can i check it.

Comment: To check the version check this out :

 http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000011375

Answer (score 0):

Update your Intel Graphics card driver.
download the small 10mb utility from here in 2 mins , it checks and gives you the latest driver and then installs it too.
Restart PC.
Now restart, VirtualBox and Geny motion
that's it, the white screen went off and all is well now.
[Intel Driver](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/detect.html?iid=dc_iduu)

Answer (score 0):

There is an explanation [here](http://shorturl.at/rvxF2) and a solution [here](https://support.genymotion.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002815177).
The solution may be applicable also for cases in which Genymotion Desktop starts but the main window does not show

Copied the info for Windows from these sources of info (info for macOS and Linux may also be found there):

On rare occasions, this happens after a Windows 10 system update. To solve this, you need to completely remove and reinstall Genymotion Desktop.
To do so, do the following:

- Remove all virtual devices (right-click on the virtual device > Delete).
- Uninstall the Genymotion Desktop
- Delete the directory %LOCALAPPDATA%\AppData\Local\Genymobile
- Run regedit and delete the key HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Genymobile
- Now reinstall the Genymotion Desktop